# How to download or tag an untagged image on ECR?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, elastic-container-registry

The UI on ECR does not let you apply tags to images. When you push images to ECR that have a tag that exists, the existing image becomes untagged, as expected. However, there does not appear to be a way to download untagged images. For example, I can't simply download the image hash

```
docker pull myarn.amazonaws.com/sandbox:e226e9aaa12beb32bfe65c571cb60605b2de13338866bc832bba0e39f6819365
Error response from daemon: manifest for myarn.amazonaws.com/sandbox:e226e9aaa12beb32bfe65c571cb60605b2de13338866bc832bba0e39f6819365 not found
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

So I discovered a user-unfriendly way of doing this. You first tag an untagged image, then you can download it. Here I tag an untagged image to `backup`

```
MANIFEST=$(aws ecr batch-get-image --repository-name sandbox --image-ids imageDigest=sha256:e226e9aaa12beb32bfe65c571cb60605b2de13338866bc832bba0e39f6819365 --query 'images[].imageManifest' --output text)
aws ecr put-image --repository-name sandbox --image-tag backup --image-manifest "$MANIFEST"
```

Then I can download it as normal

```
docker pull myarn.amazonaws.com/sandbox:backup
```

Comment: One coment, region (--region) needs to be specified in both cases

Comment: If you configure your region in your aws config, you won't have to input region, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html

Comment: Very helpful response. this improves on the documentation written here for individuals that have untagged images https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/image-retag.html

Answer (score 9):

You must use another notation that AWS suggests on its UI recently (it may not have been available that time):

`docker pull myarn.amazonaws.com/sandbox@sha256:e226e9aaa12beb32bfe65c571cb60605b2de13338866bc832bba0e39f6819365`

At least it did work with my untagged images.

Comment: It works really well to take a backup of untagged image.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming an ECR repository arn of `1283761230897.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-repository`:

To pull a docker image that is untagged, use the sha that you can copy from the ECR repository for your untagged image (Thanks to [@Győző Papp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3469555/gy%C5%91z%C5%91-papp)' answer), eg:

```
docker pull 1283761230897.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-repository@sha256:bee1809b6ab2918yfdjsajhf21398f41cfc2dcc69d27253
```

To retag it once pulled, use docker tag with whatever tag you want, the below example tags it with the tag `my-new-tag`:

```
docker tag 1283761230897.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-repository@sha256:bee1809b6ab2918yfdjsajhf21398f41cfc2dcc69d27253 1283761230897.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-repository:my-new-tag
```

Then push the tagged version back to AWS ECR:

```
docker push 1283761230897.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-repository:my-new-tag
```

You'll need to [log in to ECR locally first](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login.html) using `get-login` first though...